# Match Regular Expression in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a page location using regular expressions in JavaScript. Basically, I want to check if the string is `/dashboard` + any character, e.g., `/dashboard`, `/dashboard/activity/`, `/dashboard/myaccount`...

I tried to do it using `.*`: `/dashboard${/.*/}` but got no luck.

How should I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you just trying to see whether the target string begins with `/dashboard`? If so, the regex is just `/^dashboard/`.

Comment: I tried `location.pathname !== /^dashboard/` but it's not working

Comment: Did you mean `/^dashboard/.test(location.pathname)`?

Comment: `/^dashboard/.test(location.pathname)` this didn't work. It's accepting only `/` as well

Comment: No, it isn't. Also, post a [mcve].

Comment: It's a simple `if`. `if (isAuthenticated() && location.pathname doesn't begin with /dashboard` then execute the `if`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194191/discussion-between-melpomene-and-otavio-bonder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```js
const regex = /\/dashboard(\/\w+)*/;

const test = "/dashboard/hello".match(regex)
const testA = "/dashboard/hello/world".match(regex)
const testB = "/dashboard".match(regex)
const testC = "/hello/world".match(regex)



console.log(test);
console.log(testA);
console.log(testB);
console.log(testC);
```

Comment: `!location.pathname.match(/\/dashboard(\/\w+)*/g` worked pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: /g is for global you can remove it

Comment: Yes I removed it. Thanks!